# SQL inner join creates duplicates - why?

Tags: mysql

I have three tables and I have the following query:

```
SELECT          sfo.status,
                sfoa.company,
                sfoa.firstname,
                sfoa.lastname,
                sfoa.email,
                date_format(sfo.shipping_arrival_date,"%d.%m.%Y") AS shipping_arrival_date,
                sfoi.name,
                sfoi.qty_ordered,
FROM sales_flat_order_address AS sfoa
INNER JOIN sales_flat_order AS sfo ON sfo.entity_id=sfoa.parent_id
INNER JOIN sales_flat_order_item AS sfoi ON sfoi.order_id=sfo.entity_id
WHERE sfo.shipping_arrival_date = DATE("2016-05-03 00:00:00")
  AND (sfo.status = 'processing'
       OR sfo.status = 'pending')
```

The result is a customer and the orders he placed. But this information is recurring. So it is like

```
Customer 1 | Item 1
Customer 1 | Item 2
Customer 1 | Item 3
Customer 1 | Item 1
Customer 1 | Item 2
Customer 1 | Item 3
Customer 2 | Item 1
Customer 2 | Item 2
Customer 2 | Item 3
Customer 2 | Item 1
Customer 2 | Item 2
Customer 2 | Item 3
...
```

Why is this the case? I can use DISTINCT or group by, but why it is happening? Is it happending because of the joins? Is this normal when I use joins and whats the best way to deal with it?

Thanks.

Edit:
SQL structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sales_flat_order` (
  `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Entity Id',
  `state` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'State',
  `status` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Status',
  `coupon_code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Coupon Code',
  `protect_code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Protect Code',
  `shipping_description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Shipping Description',
  `is_virtual` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Is Virtual',
  `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Store Id',
  `customer_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Customer Id',
  `base_discount_amount` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Discount Amount',
  `base_discount_canceled` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Discount Canceled',
  `base_discount_invoiced` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Discount Invoiced',
  `base_discount_refunded` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Discount Refunded',
  `base_grand_total` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Grand Total',
  `base_shipping_amount` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Shipping Amount',
  `base_shipping_canceled` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Shipping Canceled',
  `base_shipping_invoiced` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Shipping Invoiced',
  `base_shipping_refunded` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Shipping Refunded',
  `base_shipping_tax_amount` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Shipping Tax Amount',
  `base_shipping_tax_refunded` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Shipping Tax Refunded',
  `base_subtotal` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Subtotal',
  `base_subtotal_canceled` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Subtotal Canceled',
  `base_subtotal_invoiced` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Subtotal Invoiced',
  `base_subtotal_refunded` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Subtotal Refunded',
  `base_tax_amount` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Tax Amount',
  `base_tax_canceled` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Tax Canceled',
  `base_tax_invoiced` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Tax Invoiced',
  `base_tax_refunded` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Tax Refunded',
  `base_to_global_rate` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base To Global Rate',
  `base_to_order_rate` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base To Order Rate',
  `base_total_canceled` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Total Canceled',
  `base_total_invoiced` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Total Invoiced',
  `base_total_invoiced_cost` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Total Invoiced Cost',
  `base_total_offline_refunded` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Total Offline Refunded',
  `base_total_online_refunded` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Total Online Refunded',
  `base_total_paid` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Total Paid',
  `base_total_qty_ordered` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Total Qty Ordered',
  `base_total_refunded` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Total Refunded',
  `discount_amount` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Discount Amount',
  `discount_canceled` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Discount Canceled',
  `discount_invoiced` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Discount Invoiced',
  `discount_refunded` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Discount Refunded',
  `grand_total` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Grand Total',
  `shipping_amount` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Shipping Amount',
  `shipping_canceled` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Shipping Canceled',
  `shipping_invoiced` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Shipping Invoiced',
  `shipping_refunded` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Shipping Refunded',
  `shipping_tax_amount` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Shipping Tax Amount',
  `shipping_tax_refunded` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Shipping Tax Refunded',
  `store_to_base_rate` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Store To Base Rate',
  `store_to_order_rate` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Store To Order Rate',
  `subtotal` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Subtotal',
  `subtotal_canceled` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Subtotal Canceled',
  `subtotal_invoiced` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Subtotal Invoiced',
  `subtotal_refunded` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Subtotal Refunded',
  `tax_amount` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Tax Amount',
  `tax_canceled` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Tax Canceled',
  `tax_invoiced` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Tax Invoiced',
  `tax_refunded` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Tax Refunded',
  `total_canceled` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Total Canceled',
  `total_invoiced` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Total Invoiced',
  `total_offline_refunded` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Total Offline Refunded',
  `total_online_refunded` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Total Online Refunded',
  `total_paid` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Total Paid',
  `total_qty_ordered` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Total Qty Ordered',
  `total_refunded` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Total Refunded',
  `can_ship_partially` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Can Ship Partially',
  `can_ship_partially_item` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Can Ship Partially Item',
  `customer_is_guest` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Customer Is Guest',
  `customer_note_notify` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Customer Note Notify',
  `billing_address_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Billing Address Id',
  `customer_group_id` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Customer Group Id',
  `edit_increment` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Edit Increment',
  `email_sent` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Email Sent',
  `forced_shipment_with_invoice` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Forced Do Shipment With Invoice',
  `gift_message_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Gift Message Id',
  `payment_auth_expiration` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Payment Authorization Expiration',
  `paypal_ipn_customer_notified` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Paypal Ipn Customer Notified',
  `quote_address_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Quote Address Id',
  `quote_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Quote Id',
  `shipping_address_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Shipping Address Id',
  `adjustment_negative` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Adjustment Negative',
  `adjustment_positive` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Adjustment Positive',
  `base_adjustment_negative` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Adjustment Negative',
  `base_adjustment_positive` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Adjustment Positive',
  `base_shipping_discount_amount` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Shipping Discount Amount',
  `base_subtotal_incl_tax` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Subtotal Incl Tax',
  `base_total_due` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Total Due',
  `payment_authorization_amount` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Payment Authorization Amount',
  `shipping_discount_amount` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Shipping Discount Amount',
  `subtotal_incl_tax` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Subtotal Incl Tax',
  `total_due` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Total Due',
  `weight` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Weight',
  `customer_dob` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Customer Dob',
  `increment_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Increment Id',
  `applied_rule_ids` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Applied Rule Ids',
  `base_currency_code` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Currency Code',
  `customer_email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Customer Email',
  `customer_firstname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Customer Firstname',
  `customer_lastname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Customer Lastname',
  `customer_middlename` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Customer Middlename',
  `customer_prefix` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Customer Prefix',
  `customer_suffix` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Customer Suffix',
  `customer_taxvat` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Customer Taxvat',
  `discount_description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Discount Description',
  `ext_customer_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Ext Customer Id',
  `ext_order_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Ext Order Id',
  `global_currency_code` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Global Currency Code',
  `hold_before_state` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Hold Before State',
  `hold_before_status` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Hold Before Status',
  `order_currency_code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Order Currency Code',
  `original_increment_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Original Increment Id',
  `relation_child_id` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Relation Child Id',
  `relation_child_real_id` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Relation Child Real Id',
  `relation_parent_id` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Relation Parent Id',
  `relation_parent_real_id` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Relation Parent Real Id',
  `remote_ip` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Remote Ip',
  `shipping_method` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Shipping Method',
  `store_currency_code` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Store Currency Code',
  `store_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Store Name',
  `x_forwarded_for` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'X Forwarded For',
  `customer_note` text COMMENT 'Customer Note',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Created At',
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Updated At',
  `total_item_count` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Total Item Count',
  `customer_gender` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Customer Gender',
  `base_custbalance_amount` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `currency_base_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `currency_code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `currency_rate` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `custbalance_amount` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_hold` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_multi_payment` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `real_order_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tax_percent` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tracking_numbers` text,
  `hidden_tax_amount` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Hidden Tax Amount',
  `base_hidden_tax_amount` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Hidden Tax Amount',
  `shipping_hidden_tax_amount` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Shipping Hidden Tax Amount',
  `base_shipping_hidden_tax_amnt` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Shipping Hidden Tax Amount',
  `hidden_tax_invoiced` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Hidden Tax Invoiced',
  `base_hidden_tax_invoiced` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Hidden Tax Invoiced',
  `hidden_tax_refunded` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Hidden Tax Refunded',
  `base_hidden_tax_refunded` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Hidden Tax Refunded',
  `shipping_incl_tax` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Shipping Incl Tax',
  `base_shipping_incl_tax` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Shipping Incl Tax',
  `coupon_rule_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Coupon Sales Rule Name',
  `deposit_amount` decimal(10,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `base_deposit_amount` decimal(10,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deposit_amount_refunded` decimal(10,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `base_deposit_amount_refunded` decimal(10,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deposit_amount_invoiced` decimal(10,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `base_deposit_amount_invoiced` decimal(10,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `msp_base_cashondelivery` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Msp Base Cashondelivery',
  `msp_cashondelivery` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Msp Cashondelivery',
  `msp_base_cashondelivery_incl_tax` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Msp Base Cashondelivery Incl Tax',
  `msp_cashondelivery_incl_tax` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Msp Cashondelivery Incl Tax',
  `ebizmarts_abandonedcart_flag` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ebizmarts_magemonkey_campaign_id` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping_arrival_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping_arrival_comments` text,
  `shipping_arrival_slot` text,
  `shipping_arrival_drop` text,
  `fp_abo` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_INCREMENT_ID` (`increment_id`),
  KEY `IDX_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_STATUS` (`status`),
  KEY `IDX_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_STATE` (`state`),
  KEY `IDX_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_STORE_ID` (`store_id`),
  KEY `IDX_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_CREATED_AT` (`created_at`),
  KEY `IDX_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_CUSTOMER_ID` (`customer_id`),
  KEY `IDX_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_EXT_ORDER_ID` (`ext_order_id`),
  KEY `IDX_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_QUOTE_ID` (`quote_id`),
  KEY `IDX_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_UPDATED_AT` (`updated_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Sales Flat Order' AUTO_INCREMENT=2402 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tabellenstruktur für Tabelle `sales_flat_order_address`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sales_flat_order_address` (
  `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Entity Id',
  `parent_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Parent Id',
  `customer_address_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Customer Address Id',
  `quote_address_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Quote Address Id',
  `region_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Region Id',
  `customer_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Customer Id',
  `fax` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Fax',
  `region` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Region',
  `postcode` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Postcode',
  `lastname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Lastname',
  `street` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Street',
  `city` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'City',
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Email',
  `telephone` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Telephone',
  `country_id` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Country Id',
  `firstname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Firstname',
  `address_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Address Type',
  `prefix` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Prefix',
  `middlename` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Middlename',
  `suffix` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Suffix',
  `company` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Company',
  `address_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gift_message_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tax_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vat_id` text COMMENT 'Vat Id',
  `vat_is_valid` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Vat Is Valid',
  `vat_request_id` text COMMENT 'Vat Request Id',
  `vat_request_date` text COMMENT 'Vat Request Date',
  `vat_request_success` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Vat Request Success',
  `msp_base_cashondelivery` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Msp Base Cashondelivery',
  `msp_cashondelivery` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Msp Cashondelivery',
  `msp_base_cashondelivery_incl_tax` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Msp Base Cashondelivery Incl Tax',
  `msp_cashondelivery_incl_tax` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Msp Cashondelivery Incl Tax',
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
  KEY `IDX_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_ADDRESS_PARENT_ID` (`parent_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Sales Flat Order Address' AUTO_INCREMENT=4803 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tabellenstruktur für Tabelle `sales_flat_order_item`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sales_flat_order_item` (
  `item_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Item Id',
  `order_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Order Id',
  `parent_item_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Parent Item Id',
  `quote_item_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Quote Item Id',
  `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Store Id',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Created At',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Updated At',
  `product_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Product Id',
  `product_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Product Type',
  `product_options` text COMMENT 'Product Options',
  `weight` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Weight',
  `is_virtual` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Is Virtual',
  `sku` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Sku',
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Name',
  `description` text COMMENT 'Description',
  `applied_rule_ids` text COMMENT 'Applied Rule Ids',
  `additional_data` text COMMENT 'Additional Data',
  `free_shipping` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Free Shipping',
  `is_qty_decimal` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Is Qty Decimal',
  `no_discount` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'No Discount',
  `qty_backordered` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Qty Backordered',
  `qty_canceled` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Qty Canceled',
  `qty_invoiced` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Qty Invoiced',
  `qty_ordered` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Qty Ordered',
  `qty_refunded` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Qty Refunded',
  `qty_shipped` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Qty Shipped',
  `base_cost` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Base Cost',
  `price` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Price',
  `base_price` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Base Price',
  `original_price` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Original Price',
  `base_original_price` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Original Price',
  `tax_percent` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Tax Percent',
  `tax_amount` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Tax Amount',
  `base_tax_amount` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Base Tax Amount',
  `tax_invoiced` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Tax Invoiced',
  `base_tax_invoiced` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Base Tax Invoiced',
  `discount_percent` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Discount Percent',
  `discount_amount` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Discount Amount',
  `base_discount_amount` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Base Discount Amount',
  `discount_invoiced` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Discount Invoiced',
  `base_discount_invoiced` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Base Discount Invoiced',
  `amount_refunded` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Amount Refunded',
  `base_amount_refunded` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Base Amount Refunded',
  `row_total` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Row Total',
  `base_row_total` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Base Row Total',
  `row_invoiced` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Row Invoiced',
  `base_row_invoiced` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Base Row Invoiced',
  `row_weight` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Row Weight',
  `gift_message_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Gift Message Id',
  `gift_message_available` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Gift Message Available',
  `base_tax_before_discount` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Tax Before Discount',
  `tax_before_discount` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Tax Before Discount',
  `weee_tax_applied` text COMMENT 'Weee Tax Applied',
  `weee_tax_applied_amount` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Weee Tax Applied Amount',
  `weee_tax_applied_row_amount` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Weee Tax Applied Row Amount',
  `base_weee_tax_applied_amount` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Weee Tax Applied Amount',
  `base_weee_tax_applied_row_amnt` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Weee Tax Applied Row Amnt',
  `weee_tax_disposition` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Weee Tax Disposition',
  `weee_tax_row_disposition` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Weee Tax Row Disposition',
  `base_weee_tax_disposition` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Weee Tax Disposition',
  `base_weee_tax_row_disposition` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Weee Tax Row Disposition',
  `ext_order_item_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Ext Order Item Id',
  `locked_do_invoice` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Locked Do Invoice',
  `locked_do_ship` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Locked Do Ship',
  `price_incl_tax` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Price Incl Tax',
  `base_price_incl_tax` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Price Incl Tax',
  `row_total_incl_tax` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Row Total Incl Tax',
  `base_row_total_incl_tax` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Row Total Incl Tax',
  `hidden_tax_amount` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Hidden Tax Amount',
  `base_hidden_tax_amount` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Hidden Tax Amount',
  `hidden_tax_invoiced` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Hidden Tax Invoiced',
  `base_hidden_tax_invoiced` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Hidden Tax Invoiced',
  `hidden_tax_refunded` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Hidden Tax Refunded',
  `base_hidden_tax_refunded` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Hidden Tax Refunded',
  `is_nominal` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Is Nominal',
  `tax_canceled` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Tax Canceled',
  `hidden_tax_canceled` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Hidden Tax Canceled',
  `tax_refunded` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Tax Refunded',
  `base_tax_refunded` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Tax Refunded',
  `discount_refunded` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Discount Refunded',
  `base_discount_refunded` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Discount Refunded',
  `deposit_amount` decimal(10,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `base_deposit_amount` decimal(10,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `substitute` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`),
  KEY `IDX_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_ITEM_ORDER_ID` (`order_id`),
  KEY `IDX_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_ITEM_STORE_ID` (`store_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Sales Flat Order Item' AUTO_INCREMENT=20955 ;
```

Comment: if you don't use aggregate function the right solution is the use of distinct .

Comment: because you have missed a check, there must be a condition that needs to be written there...

Comment: write down the schema, we might help you

Comment: Include the Order # (eg. entity_id) in the output and I suspect the results "will make sense". Just showing the Customer and Item *loses* a key part of the key-tuple. If this is still not the case then the multiplicity and 1-M relationship assumptions are incorrect.

Comment: If you don't show us the query, we can't really help

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo I added the structure to the post.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to be sure without the schema but the duplication you are seeing could be items 1,2, and 3 for each order for that address.